# Creating a char* of specific format with specific values

Tags: c++, sqlite, type-conversion

I am attempting to create a char* type in a specific format, using values given by the other areas of the program, the values within the VALUES() brackets are the values that are given by the program.
The format should look like so:

```
  char* sql = "INSERT INTO RecurringEvents (title,description,duration,recurtype,startfrom,endingtype,dateend,occurences,venueid) "  \
         "VALUES ('title','description','duration','recurtype','startfrom','endingtype','dateend',occurences,venueid); "
```

As you can see, text values must be within '  ' punctuation, while int values are left alone, so a usual command may be like so:

```
"INSERT INTO RecurringEvents (title,description,duration,recurtype,startfrom,endingtype,dateend,occurences,venueid) "  \
     "VALUES ('thetitle','thedesc','theduration','recurtype','startfrom','enddddtype','dateend',2,4); ";
```

The function in which this is required is below,not that it all matters, but to explain, it converts the event's(class) data all into string/int values, so they can be used to form an INSERT command(this is the proble), and then executed on a database, once this is done (and the record is verified for plausability) its added to the vector and the database is closed.

```
void addRecEvent(newRecurringEvent event, vector <newRecurringEvent> &events){
    sqlite3 *db;
    int rc;
    char *sql;
    int tableCheck;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    rc = sqlite3_open("data.sqlite", &db);
    string title = event.getTitle();
    string description = event.getDescription();
    string duration = to_string(event.getDuration());
    string recurType = recToString(event.getRecurType());
    string startfrom = to_string( event.getStartFrom());
    string endingtype = etypeToStr(event.getEndingType());
    string dateend = to_string(event.getDateEnd());
    int occurences = event.getOccurences();
    int venueid = event.getVenuid();
    /*CREATE INSERT COMMAND USING char*sql  IN FORMAT REQUIRED*/
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg); //execute the command
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK){
        cout << stderr << "SQL error: %s \n", zErrMsg;

    }
    else{
        cout << stdout << "Records created succesfully";
        events.push_back(event);
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);


}
```

I once attempted to create the format all in string within another function (by passing the values to it), and then returning it as a char*, but came accross the problem of the single quotation marks used on the text fields (like title,description etc).

Sorry if any of this is confusing, but to make it short, I just want to form a character sequence in the format in the first snippet of code, that uses given values to form its sequence.Any help is appreciated, as I am new to c++.

Comment: Use a [prepared statement](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) and bind your dynamic arguments depending on their type, then execute the statement. The binder sorts out what do to with the data, and more importantly, safely forms the statement and avoid sql injection risks. This is the universal preference for sql back-ends that support it (most do, including sqlite).

Comment: You cannot create a `char*` in a particular format; it's up to the compiler to determine how a `char*` is represented. Your question is about an **array of `char`**, which is not the same as a pointer to `char`.

Answer (score 0):

The comment left by whozcraig solved my question, I must use a prepared statement to feed my values to the statement